# How do I retrieve an OWL Datatype Definition using the owl api

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I do have a bunch of OWLDataRanges which look something like this when the toString-method is used:

> DataRangeRestriction(xsd:string facetRestriction(pattern "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[T]{1}[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[Z]{1}"^^xsd:string))

What I want is the part in brackets after "facetRestriction". I guess I have to use some visitor pattern, but I don't really understand how they work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't have to use a visitor, just use the correspdoning method `facetRestrictions` for each `OWLDatatypeRestriction` object: https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDatatypeRestriction.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. OWLDataRange does not have the facetRestrictions-method though, but I was able to cast it to OWLDatatypeRestriction. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: true, it's a subinterface. But you can check for type in advance also via `getDataRangeType()` - in case of nested `OWLDataRange`s like intersection, union , complement indeed a visitor would be necessary to cover all facets. But I guess in your case this does never occur - those complex data ranges are used quite rarely from what I've seen so far